# Regex to ignore spaces

Tags: python, python-2.7

In my program, I will accept 16 digit number in two different formats and masks the numbers in between. (It will only show the first 6 numbers, and last 4 numbers)

1. (with spaces) 1111 1111 1111 1111
2. (without spaces) 1111111111111111

Currently, the regex in the code only masks the numbers without spaces. Can someone help me edit the regex so that it also masks the numbers that has spaces?

```
import csv
import re

find_and_mask_cc = lambda s: re.sub(r'(\d{6})\d{6}(\d{4})', r'\1XXXXXX\2', s)

with open('CSV_sample_file.csv') as file1, open('CSV_sample_file2.csv', 'w') as file2:
    reader = csv.reader(file1)
    writer = csv.writer(file2)
    writer.writerow(next(reader))
    writer.writerows(map(find_and_mask_cc, row) for row in reader)
```

Comment: `replace(" ", "")` use replace here I think

Comment: I have attached a sample code, thank you!

Comment: Hi, you may have a look at negative lookahead, like \d{6}(?!\d{5}), it will match your second case, but I didn't find how to deal with spaces.

Answer (score 0):

```
answer = str(input).replace(' ','')
```

Answer (score 0):

Either replace the spaces with an empty string, or include optional whitespace in the regex: `r'(\d{6}\s?)\d{6}\s?(\d{4})'`

Answer (score 0):

```
reg = "((?<=^\d{6})|(?<=^\d{4} \d{2}))(.*)(?=\d{4}$)"
str1 = "1111111111111111"
str2 = "1111 1111 1111 1111"
m1 = re.search(reg, str1)
m2 = re.search(reg, str2)
res1 = str1[:m1.start()] + re.sub("\d", "*", m1.group(0)) + str1[m1.end():]
res2 = str2[:m2.start()] + re.sub("\d", "*", m2.group(0)) + str2[m2.end():]

>>> res1
'111111******1111'
>>> res2
'1111 11** **** 1111'
```